# when does re-render happen exactly in vue?

Tags: vuejs2

I understand that Vue will re-render when the data changes. But when I change the data in a hook function like `mounted`, the page does not re-render. Below is part of my code.

```
 mounted: function () {
  document.getElementById('lanchange').onclick = function (e) {
    this.loginPopActive = false
    this.lanPopActive = false
    console.log(this.lanPopActive)
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to bind this properly inside your click handler. Use an arrow function, closure, or bind. Or better yet, bind the handler with Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has an issue with `this`.  Use an arrow function, a closure, or `bind`.

```
mounted: function () {
  document.getElementById('lanchange').onclick = (e) = >{
    this.loginPopActive = false
    this.lanPopActive = false
    console.log(this.lanPopActive)
  }
}
```

Comment: could u pls explain a little bit more? or is there any info in the vue documentation? thanks very much!

Comment: @HM-Dave It's not a Vue issue. When you attach a handler as you have this will point to the lanchange element. You need to make this point to the Vue, because you are trying to change properties of the Vue using this.